# closest number, based on two numbers

Tags: javascript

Im currently checking what the closest number would be compared to an array:

```
var testarray1 = [4054,4938,4983,1928,8833];
var test = 5000;

var result = testarray1.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - postcode) < Math.abs(prev - postcode) ? curr : prev);
  }
```

This works fine.

but when i have it like multi numbers in one, it dosent work:

```
var testarray1 = ["4000-5595","4400-4720"];
var test = 4630;

for (var x =0; x < testarray1.length; x++) {
      var selectedPostcode = testarray1[x][0];
      var splitted = selectedPostcode.split("-");
      var from = parseInt(splitted[0]);
      var to = parseInt(splitted[1]);
      if (postcode >= from && postcode <= to) {
        return selectedPostcode;
        break;
      }
    }
```

in the example code above, it would return "4000-5595", but how can i do so it selects the closest one, in this case it would be the "4400-4720"?

Comment: you shouldn't use 'from' as a variable name

Comment: At least this line `var selectedPostcode = input[x][0];` is problematic, as it always only selects the first character of the strings (`"4"` with your example input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below. Explanation is in comments.

```js
var testarray1 = ["4000-5595", "4400-4720"];
var postcode = 4630;

// Take two variables to set difference and result
// set difference default value to -1
var difference = -1;
var result = "";

for (var x = 0; x < testarray1.length; x++) {
  // use testarray1[x] instead of testarray1[x][0]
  var selectedPostcode = testarray1[x];
  var splitted = selectedPostcode.split("-");
  var from = parseInt(splitted[0]);
  var to = parseInt(splitted[1]);

  if (postcode >= from && postcode <= to) {
    // get difference
    let currDiff = Math.abs(postcode - from) + Math.abs(postcode - to);
    // difference = -1 means there is no existing value so set current as result
    // check current difference is less than existing one.
    if (difference == -1 || currDiff < difference) {
      difference = currDiff;
      result = selectedPostcode;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want closest value based on minimum difference from either one of the value then use  `let currDiff = Math.min(Math.abs(postcode - from), Math.abs(postcode - to));`.

```js
var testarray1 = ["4000-5595", "4400-4720", '4800-5000'];
var postcode = 4630;

// Take two variables to set difference and result
// set difference default value to -1
var difference = -1;
var result = "";

for (var x = 0; x < testarray1.length; x++) {
  // use testarray1[x] instead of testarray1[x][0]
  var selectedPostcode = testarray1[x];
  var splitted = selectedPostcode.split("-");
  var from = parseInt(splitted[0]);
  var to = parseInt(splitted[1]);

  if (postcode >= from && postcode <= to) {
    // get difference
    let currDiff = Math.min(Math.abs(postcode - from), Math.abs(postcode - to));
    // difference = -1 means there is no existing value so set current as result
    // check current difference is less than existing one.
    if (difference == -1 || currDiff < difference) {
      difference = currDiff;
      result = selectedPostcode;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for every interval and check if previous ans is closet or current interval is closet and change ans accordingly like this.

```js
var testarray1 = ['4000-5595', '4400-4720']
var test = 4630
let ans

for (var x = 0; x < testarray1.length; x++) {
  var selectedPostcode = testarray1[x]
  var splitted = selectedPostcode.split('-')
  var from = parseInt(splitted[0])
  var to = parseInt(splitted[1])

  if (ans) {
    if (ans[0] < from || ans[1] > to) ans = [from, to]
  } else {
    if (test >= from && test <= to) {
      ans = [from, to]
    }
  }
}

console.log(ans.join('-'))
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this code. If you add a range that obviously should not match, it becomes the result. E.g. for `var testarray1 = ['4000-5595', '4400-4720', '4800-5000'];` `""4800-5000""` is returned. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwu7g9bq/